# Remove name of the source in bibliography list

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I use TeX for writing my thesis. In bibliography list I need to remove a source number.

Now when I cite some source I use standard `cite` tag, e.g.:

`\cite[p.~234]{AuthorName}` and in document there will a citation "[12, p. 234]" (I need to change "[]" for "()") where number 12 is number of the source in bibliography list.

But I need to change citation style to cite name of the author, year (and page), e.g.:

"(Horstmann, 2001, p. 234)"

I can do it when I set author name and year in bibliography:

> \bibitem[Horstmann, 2001]{Horstmann} HORSTMANN, C.S. \textit{Big Java:
>   Programming and Practice}. 1st. ed. New York, USA: John Wiley \& Sons,
>   Inc., 2001, 1231 s. \ISBN{978-0471402480}.

ut on the left side of this citation there is a name of this source "[Horstmann, 2001] ....." and I don't want it there.

Is it possible to remove this name of the source so the citation will be only:

HORSTMANN, C.S. Big Java: ....

?

Answer (score 1):

For hand built citations all you need to do is load the [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite[p.~234]{Horstmann}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem[Horstmann, 2001]{Horstmann} HORSTMANN, C.S. \textit{Big Java:
  Programming and Practice}. 1st. ed. New York, USA: John Wiley \&
  Sons, Inc., 2001, 1231 s. ISBN 978-0471402480.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

However, also have a look using the newer biblatex and/or using an external bibtex database.